# Create dangling commit without checking out

Tags: git

Is there a way to silently create a commit that is

- Not connected to the current branch
- Not checked out afterwards

like

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G   # master
       \   \
        X   Y
```

Where `X` and `Y` are created without the user noticing.

The reasoning:

I am writing a lot of exploratory experiment-code and want to automatically commit the current state when running an experiment. These intermediate states should not end up in my Git history and I do not want to go through the mental overhead of committing before running all the time (or forgetting it every now and then).

The idea is to have a lot of dangling commits that will not be pushed to my remote and may be deleted by garbage collection. Each individual commit SHA1 will be annotated to my experiment results, enabling me to trace back what changes had what effect on the results.

Comment: `git commit-tree` looks like what you want. You use it to create a commit unassociated with any branch and not checked out.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's exactly what I would've answered, with one addition: stage all the changes first. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @hvd Okay, I wrote it up.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `git commit-tree` command to create a dangling commit.

First, stage the files you want to commit, e.g., by doing `git add file`.

Next, create a tree from the index.

```
git write-tree
```

This will print a hash to stdout. That is the hash of the tree you want to commit. Let's say the hash is `12345678`.

Now that you have a tree for the index, you can unstage the changes so you won't commit them "for real" by mistake. (`git reset HEAD file`.)

Finally, create a commit from that tree.

```
git commit-tree 12345678 -p HEAD -m "Description"
```

This creates a new commit and prints its hash to stdout. The commit's parent is `HEAD` and the comment is `Description`.

As a reminder, this is a dangling commit and therefore will be subject to GC.

Comment: Note that dangling commits are generally safe for roughly 14 days as this is the default `gc.pruneExpire` time (see the git config documentation).

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
$ git commit -m 'Foo'
[my_branch b54ed59] Foo
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

you will find that the commit you reset has not disappeared, but still exists, so that you can do

```
git checkout b54ed59
```

and get back to that commit, dangling off your branch.

Tagging the commit would allow you to preserve it forever.

Comment: But the hard reset will delete all the changes. I want the workspace to remain untouched.

Comment: Then do a soft reset?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way than the `git commit-tree` I suggested in another answer is to create a detached head and commit into it.

```
git checkout HEAD^{commit}
```

This keeps you at the same commit, but you are now detached from the branch, so any future commits will not update the branch. Commit your changes, and then check the original branch back out, leaving your commits dangling.

Comment: You can also use `git checkout --detach <current-branch-name>`, though this requires knowing the current branch name. (You can find that with `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.)

Answer (score 0):

### Keeping your history:

I am going to give you an answer accomplishes your goals, but in a different mindset than what you are asking. While you can get by by having commits floating around in reflog, we aren't doing that here.

You are going to make a series of commits to one branch. You care about each commit, because you need to reference them from your tests. After you have a working branch, and you want to share your work with remote, we will change our history.

#### Assumptions:

You have an `origin/master`, `master`, and `dev` branch

#### How to:

We need two sets of code. If you don't want to do this over and over again we can store these as functions in [.bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file). Every time you run your code you will call the function that automatically commits and runs the code.

**1) committing every time you run the code:**

```
git add --all
git commit --allow-empty-message -m '' 
<command for running code>
```

Now you will have SHA1 for every run, and you will have a history of your development (locally). To show what each commit did, you can do a `git log --patch` to show the line changes for each commit.

Next we will change our history before sharing it with remote. We will squash all your changes into one commit.

**2) sharing your work with remote:**

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash dev
git commit -m "<commit message for dev history>"
#fetch & push to origin/master after dealing with any remote issues.
```

This takes all the patches from each tiny commit, and merges them all into one patch, with one SHA1 and one message.

At this point, you can force-update your dev branch with your new history `git branch -f dev`, and then the garbage collection can take those commits you've squashed.

### Conclusion

This accomplishes your goal of handling many commits that will not be pushed to your remote and may be deleted by garbage collection (after you are done with them). Each individual commit SHA1 can be annotated to your experiment results, enabling you to trace back what changes had what effect on the results for each time you run your code. It also allows you to version control (locally) your changes.